# With Asp.Net Mvc programmatically define section name in content page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm not talking about the RenderSection and my question is not related direcly with layout page.

First of all i want to tell you what im trying to do. I have a

```
public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Ordering { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public string ModulePath { get; set; }
    public bool ShowTitle { get; set; }
}
```

table named Module. Modules are like Widgets. Please pay attention to the Position and ModulePath fields.

Positions are like ContentPlaceHolder defined in Layout page. In Mvc i define position like below.

```
RenderSection("PositionName", required:false)
```

ModulePath field holds the PartialView's location. They will be rendered in layout.

Problem starts here. How to do this programmatically.

Normally we use;

```
@section PositionName
{
   @html.Partial(...)
}
```

to define a section in content page.

In Asp.net WebForms it is very easy to do.

```
ContentPlaceHolder.FindControl(PositionName).Controls.Add(..)
```

**I need to specify section names programmatically, which is in a content page**

Actually i need something like this;

```
foreach(var item in Model.Modules)
{
   this.AddSection(item.Position, item.ModulePath, item.Ordering)
}
```

Manual way

```
@section PositionName
{
    @html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/AModule.cshtml")
    @html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/AnotherModule.cshtml")
    @html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/AnotherModule.cshtml")
}
```

I tried;

```
@section @SectionName
{
   ...
}
```

ofcource failed.

So its very good idea to dynamically place PartialViews anywhere of page which their positions setted at administration panel. Thats what im trying to do.

Comment: You could use helpers to render partials for you, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You can write a helper method to do almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge there's no option to do this within ASP.NET MVC, but it should be do-able.

As pages are rendered into HTML they get added to the `ViewContext` object, so I imagine you'd want to replace areas of the HTML with your rendered view. You can access the current rendered HTML as a string like so:

```
var htmlContent = string.Empty;
var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, relativePath, null);
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    var context = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view.View, ViewData, TempData, writer);
    view.View.Render(context, writer);
    writer.Flush();
    htmlContent = writer.ToString();
}
```

With this in mind you could programatically replace areas of the string by using some kind of tag that you could match against.

Comment: hmm, need some research about background works then. it may be good look around the web about razor's work mechanism.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely going to require some digging and researching. It's an interesting problem and I'd love to hear your solution when you figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a section programmatically like this:

```
DefineSection("YoursectionName", async (a) =>
{

     this.Write(await this.Component.InvokeAsync(widget.Name, widget.Parameters));

});
```

Essentially, you would do a `Select` over all the sections and define the section for each by invoking the given component and then writing the resulting HTML.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to dynamically add a section, but you can dynamically render things *within* an existing section. For example:

```
@section FooPosition
{
    foreach (var module in models.Where(m => m.Position == "FooPosition"))
    {
        @Html.Partial(...);
    }
}
```

In other words, you define sections for the available positions, and then allow the module to have only one of those available positions. Then, you just render whatever modules belong to that position inside the section.

Comment: what bout ordering? can you figure out anything about it? We may also specify module orders.

Comment: @BulutParadise `.Where` is Linq.  Just add an `OrderBy`.